# Saving RGB Images in CUDA

Tags: image, cuda, gpu

I have an rgb image data in the first 3 channels of a uchar4 array. Is there a function that I can utilize in CUDA libraries in order to save this uchar4 format as an RGB image, or is there another way for saving RGB images in CUDA?

Comment: That is not really CUDA's responsibility. Just write the data back to the host and use whatever imaging saving routine/library you like.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also, I found a practical function in CUDA SDK Helper libraries. Casting uchar4 as unsigned char and using "savePPM4ub" function in sdkHelper.h, the 4th channel of the uchar4 array is stripped and the image is saved as a 3-channel RGB image in ppm format.

Comment: @Bart: I think your comment would be a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving RGB image data to a file does not involve CUDA. You use CUDA to process your data in whichever way you desire.

Once that is done and you have achieved a result, copy your RGB data back to the host and save it. You can basically pick whatever your favorite routine/library is to save RGB data to a file. [Boost.GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) as recommended by Roger Dahl does seem to be a nice option indeed.

As such, there is no particular functionality within CUDA that allows you to save your image data to a file.